# Deployment rule set Cert error

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on deployment rule set (DRS). I have a signed jar file and xml containing rule set.
I have deployed the signed jar file and the xml in the C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment folder.
I can also view the xml file in the "View the active Deployment Rule Set" link in Security tab of Java Control Panel
Security level is high
Java home directs to 1.8_66 and all the env variable seem to be fine.
Currently 3 versions of java are installed, 1.6_45, 1.8_66 and 1.8_71 (visible in java control panel).

Issue,

http://xyz.abc.com has a rule set of 1.6+ with permission run. However, when I click on the link xyz.abc.com, a button on the page doesnt show up and "Error... click for details" is displayed in its place.

On clicking the error, I get a popup with name "Application Error", saying

NoClassDefFoundError

matrix/util/CallbackListener

On clicking on details and select from menu options, I can see the error as

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.security.cert.CRLException: Empty input
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.retrieveCRL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.reset(Unknown Source)
    ........................

Caused by: java.security.cert.CRLException: Empty input
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCRL(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCRL(Unknown Source)
    ........................
```

Can anyone give me pointers where I am going wrong.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Based only in the stacktrace of the exception (since I don't really know what's your code doing under the scenes), I believe your problem is that the certificate revokation list does not contain any revoked certificate (Serial Numbers) and the Java CertPath provider can't handle an empty list.
Can you check the CRL Distribution Point and see if it has revoked certificates? If it does, you must add a debug option to your code (maybe a try/catch too) to see what method is throwing the exception.